# MVC Razor button click even pass parameter with it

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to MVC Razor.

I have this view:

```
@model SuburbanCustPortal.Models.CustomerModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Summary";
}

<h2>Customer Summary Screen</h2>
<p>
    Please select an account below or add an existing account.
</p>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Existing Accounts</legend>

      @Html.Action("ExistingAccounts2")

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add an Account" />
      </p>


    </fieldset>
  </div>
}
```

Which calls this method:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ExistingAccounts2()
{
  return PartialView("ExistingAccounts", _client.RequestCustomersForAccount(User.Identity.Name));
}
```

Which in turn calls this partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData >

<br />
<br />
<table>

  @if (Model != null)
  {
    foreach (var usr in Model)
    {
      <tr>      
        <td>
          <input id="btnShowCustomer" name="btnShowCustomer2" type="submit" value="View"/>           
        </td>
        <td>
          @usr.AccountId
        </td>
        <td>
          @usr.Name
        </td>
@*        <td>
          @usr.DeliveryStreet
        </td>*@
      </tr>
    }
  }

</table>
<br />
```

Which ends up displaying this:

[image]

This works up to this point.

What I want to so is be able to click on the button next to the customer's name and it pull up the customer's account.

How do I tie that customer to the button to know who to pull up and how do have the button click pull it up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the Customer Number back once the button is clicked:

If you have the customer number as a property in the Model you could do something like:

```
<input id="btnShowCustomer" data-customerNumber="@usr.CustomerNumber" />
```

You could then `POST` this data to the Server using an @Html.ActionLink, @Ajax.ActionLink, or jQuery:

*Action Link*

```
@Html.ActionLink("LoadInfo", "Info", new {customerId=@usr.CustomerNumber})
```

*jQuery*

```
$("#btnShowCustomer").click(function() {

 var customerId = $("#btnShowCustomer").attr("data-customerNumber");
  $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
       data: "customerId=" + customerId, 
       url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")', 
       success: function (result) { 

       } 
 });
```

Comment: got error -- "data-customerNumber not valid attribute for element input "

Comment: How would I then in my controller obtain this information?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the trick ! oid would be the id of the customer (i dont think the path is ok :) )

```
@Ajax.RawActionLink("Action", "Controller", new { oid = '@Model.customerID'}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "the view you want to show" }, new { id = "btnNewB", @class = "your btn class" })
```

good luck ;)

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol "RawActionLink". How do I get it to see the RawActionLink?

Comment: hmm..that shuld not happen ... what's the exact error you get ?

Comment: Exactly that in visual studio:  Cannot resolve symbol "RawActionLink".

Comment: Hmmm ... That's something that never happened to me.I would look into it .. but i'm kinda busy to tell you the truth. Either make a new question asking that or use Darren's answer. That works aswell. Hope it works out