# MVC button onClick

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making my MVC application. How do I create a button in my view that a click on it will run a function from controller. I would also like to pass data from the view that the button is in. But I do not want to open a different view. I just want to run a function - Button "save to file" would save the table from the view into a file - would open a Directory browser and save a file on a disk.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? A normal ajax or form submit to a ActionResult which returns JSON data or a ParticalView should work like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318905/mvc-razor-button-click-even-pass-parameter-with-it) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822114/passing-parameters-to-controller-on-click-of-a-button)

Comment: You need to make an effort to put together some code to get better responses.  Take a look at Html.ActionLink.  Or you can simply have <A href="../ControllerName/MethodName" in the View and in MethodName method in controller, return a file as a response.

Comment: I'm agree with the other friends. More explaining needed! Also check out for Html.RenderPartial too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the correct solution was to use

```
@Html.ActionLink("weekly - PDF", "GenerateTable", "Account", new { group_id = Model.group_id, class_id = Model.class_id, type = 1 }, null)
```

And in `GenerateTable` method just return a proper file.

Answer (score 1):

This will be done with the help of ajax request from your view. You need to add a simple button on your view and call a jquery function on its onclick event like this:

```
<input type="button" value="save to file" onclick="saveToFile()" />
```

Then you can create saveToFile function to send ajax request like this: here you can create your data as per your need of fields you want to post to controller. I just adding firstField and secondField for demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = { "firstField" : "value1", "secondField": "value2" };
    function saveToFile() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your action method will be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UseShippingAddress(string firstField, string secondField)
{
    //write your logic here to save the file on a disc            
    return Json("1");
}
```